# Classic Conundrum: How do I map a Sub-Domain in Wordpress?

Tags: subdomains

I have the domain name: **www.get-murmur.com**, and I wanted to set up the sub-domain **blog.get-murmur.com**, which should point to my wordpress website: **murmurapp.wordpress.com**.

I created an image (below) that explains my current predicament. I know I'm getting close, but then I make a wrong move and get further away. If you can look at this image, that would be very helpful.

I tried to toggle the different combinations a bunch of times (no masking, no forwarding, update primary domain, etc.) so I'm starting to believe it's something I'm not thinking about entirely.

Again, many thanks!

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/murmur-photos/fixingit.png

[image: My Situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your name-servers with wordpress.com name-servers.

Before Upgrading - Important Notes

WordPress.com automatically removes the “www” from all URLs. Mapping the “www” subdomain is not supported. Also, they do not currently allow mapping to subdirectories, such as example.com/blog.

**Instructions for Mapping Subdomains**

1. Add a CNAME record through the registrar where you purchased your domain or through your DNS provider. You should NOT change your Name Server information if you wish to only map a subdomain. The CNAME should look something like the following (please note the fullstop character at the end of each domain name):

**blog.get-murmur.com. IN CNAME murmurapp.wordpress.com.**

2. Once the CNAME record has been added and verified, go to Domains and add the subdomain to your blog. If everything is configured correctly, you will be prompted to pay for the upgrade and complete the mapping process.
   [image]
3. After you have made your purchase, go to My Domains, select the
   radio button next to your custom domain, and click the Update
   Primary Domain button.
   [image]
   Please note, you may see a Redirect Loop error page if you immediately visit your site after setting a new Primary Domain. This is usually fixed within a few seconds by refreshing the page.

**Adding a Subdomain if your Domain is Registered Elsewhere and Mapped to WordPress.com**

Occasionally even if you already use a domain that you’ve registered elsewhere with your WordPress.com blog, you may wish to have a subdomain as well. For example, you already own the domain get-murmur.com, which you have mapped to your WordPress.com blog at murmurapp.wordpress.com. Now you want a new domain called blog.get-murmur.com.

Your murmurapp.wordpress.com which will hold the content at blog.get-murmur.com. Be sure to do this while logged in as the same user that owns the primary domain.

Once the new blog has been created, while still in your kittens.wordpress.com Dashboard, map your new subdomain directly through WordPress.com. So in this example, you would purchase domain mapping for blog.get-murmur.com.

Be sure to set your new subdomain blog.get-murmur.com as your primary domain in My Domains in your murmurapp.wordpress.com Dashboard.

Note: if your domain is already registered with WordPress.com or mapped to a WordPress.com blog, you do not need to add any kind of CNAME record.

Comment: Yes! It finally worked. A couple of things confused me when I first read it but once you pointed me back to this page, I finally got it. The problem was the CNAME. I should NOT have touched the name-servers and only changed the CNAME. You really helped me a lot!

Comment: @alex,  I have a similar question. I have a domain with Bluehost (BH) and the site is hosted with Inmotion (IM). At IM, I have a WP multisite at the root. I am cloning the multisite onto a subdomain for testing purposes (I did it once, took several days, but now I don't remember the path again). So do I need to create the CNAME at Bluehost (the reason is that BH does not give access to almost anything if you use it only to park a domain). I have verified tables wp-blogs, options, file wp-config, .htaccess. thank you.